# How to set pagination and set limit that show per page 5 items in lumen

Tags: lumen

How to set pagination and set limit that show per page 5 items. When I pass page no. its show that page items

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller{


    public function index(){

        $Employees  = Employees::all();

        $limit=5;
        $itemPerPage=5;
        $response = array();

        $count  = Employees::count();
        $totalPage= ceil($count/$itemPerPage);

        $response['totalPages'] = $totalPage;
        $response['data'] = $Employees;
        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try laravel `paginate` function to get result with pagination

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

Try the sample code from laracasts discuss Channel

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/pagination-in-lumen?page=1

Hope this will help

Comment: check my answer its more easy

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index(){

        $Employees  = Employees::all();
        $page = Input::get('page', 1); 


        $itemPerPage=5;
        $response = array();

        $count  = Employees::count();

        $offSet = ($page * $itemPerPage) - $itemPerPage;

        $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($Employees->toArray(), $offSet, $itemPerPage, true);

       return new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($Employees), $itemPerPage, $page);

    }
```